# How to remove the shadow in the Xamarin.Forms application

Tags: scroll, xamarin.forms, shadow

When scrolling from above and below appears a white shadow, how can I remove it?
The application uses the "ThriveGmbH.BottomNavigationBar.XF" library, but this shadow appears on regular pages

[Top of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ktw7j.jpg)

[Bottom of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRdo2.jpg)

Comment: Does this happens only on the XF app or in other apps too ?

Comment: On all application pages @FabriBertani

Comment: It might be display due to scroll. Please check that.

Comment: Yes, the top appears at the beginning of the scrolling, the bottom disappears when the page is scrolled to the end @Srusti Thakkar

Comment: Try to remove scroll once and check shadow is still there?

Comment: I looked that on the page without scrolling this shadow also exists @Srusti Thakkar

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: This problem also occurs on newly created pages @Srusti Thakkar

Comment: Can't tell anything without showing your code